# MySQL: How can I select only those entrys that never had a specific value in a column?

Tags: mysql

I currently use a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT
    testcase.foreignID, testcaseexecution.Result
FROM
    mydb.testcaseexecution
INNER JOIN mydb.testcase ON testcaseexecution.Testcase_idTestcase = testcase.idTestcase
```

What I would like to do is to display only those foreignIDs where testcaseexecution.Result has never been 'OK' and in addition only display them once per **foreignID**.

I tinkered around using **DISTINCT** but didn't get it to work, please help.

Example:

```
foreignID    Result
--------------------
1            NOK
1            wait for test
2            OK
2            NOK
3            NOK
```

This should yield the result:

```
foreignID
----------
1         
3
```

Comment: can you please add some sample data and required output data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation on the `foreignID` column and check for the presence of an OK result:

```
SELECT t2.foreignID
FROM mydb.testcaseexecution t1
INNER JOIN mydb.testcase t2
    ON t1.Testcase_idTestcase = t2.idTestcase
GROUP BY t2.foreignID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t1.Result = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is a good direction if you would like to get the list of ID's only, you may want to change it to a `GROUP BY` depending on your use case and business requirements.

In case the foreignID is PK or unique in the testcase table, you don't need the `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT /* Get a distinct list */
  TC.foreignID
FROM
  mydb.testcase TC
WHERE
  /* Exclude everything which ever had a corresponding record with Result = 'OK' */
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM mydb.testcaseexecution TCE
    WHERE TC.idTestcase = Testcase_idTestcase
      AND TCE.Result = 'OK'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. hope it should be working fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    foreignID
FROM
    testcaseexecution
WHERE
    foreignID NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            foreignID
        FROM
            testcaseexecution
        WHERE
            Result = 'OK'
    );
```

[LIVE DEMO SQL](http://rextester.com/AKHPY9701)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `not exists` and `distinct` to do that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    foreignID
FROM
    testcase t1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            testcaseexecution t2
        WHERE
            t1.idTestcase = t2.Testcase_idTestcase
        AND t2.Result = 'OK'
    );
```

<del>[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d86bd/1)</del>

Comment: Based on the original query, the `foreignID` column is located in the `testcase` table, not in the `testcaseexecution` and the linking column is not  the `foreignID`, but the `idTestcase` and `Testcase_idTestcase`. The theory is good tho.

Comment: @Pred Good catch, I've updated my answer. Upvote yours.